# What's the neatest way to get a value from a dictionary and convert to an integer if it exists – in python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm looking for a neater way to retrieve a value from a dictionary (if it exists) and convert to an integer (or replace with 0) using python 3.8.

Here's the code I'm using now:

```py
import re
data = {"x":"10", "y":"blank"}

for key in data.keys():
    n = data.get(key,0)
    n = int(n) if re.search("[0-9]+", n) else 0
    print(n)
```

I'd like to condense the `int` conversion into one line – possibly without regex? Is that possible? Or perhaps using a pipe feature to move the logic to to the same line?

Comment: n = math.isnan(n)?0: int(n)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one line without regex like this:

```
data = {k: int(n) if n.isnumeric() else 0 for k, n in data.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use comprehension to get it all in one line

```
import re
data = {"x":"10", "y":"blank"}

data = {k:int(v) if re.search("^[0-9]+$", v) else 0 for k, v in data.items()}
```

Comment: @BryanOakley hmmm, I see what you mean. It's easy to fix ... fixed.